# How To Print Value From NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nslog

### HI in below code i store Data in nsuserdefault but i want to see my data what i entered so how i print my data in user default

```
userRegistrationClass *userData = [[userRegistrationClass alloc] init];

  userData.strName = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"Name"];
  userData.strEmail = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"Email-ID"];
  userData.strGender = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"Gender(Male Or Female)"];
  userData.strUserName = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"User Name"];
  userData.strPassword = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"Password"];
  userData.strRePass = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"Re-Enter Password"];
  userData.strBirthDte = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"Birth Day"];
  userData.strMbleNum = [dicUserData objectForKey:@"Mobile Number"];

NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userData];
userDataStore = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDataStore setObject:personEncodedObject forKey:@"User Name"];
[userDataStore synchronize];
```

Comment: in what way does not work? What's up?

Comment: actually i want to know what data store in my nsuserdefault and i have no idea how i print my data in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to archive the object before storing it to the NSUserDefaults, if all the key-value stored in dictionary are NSNUmber or NSString.

```
NSData *personEncodedObject         = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userData];
     NSUserDefaults *userDataStore = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [userDataStore setObject:personEncodedObject forKey:@"User Name"];
     [userDataStore synchronize];


 NSData *dataFromDefaults = [userDataStore objectForKey:@"User Name"];
 NSDictionary *receivedDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataFromDefaults];

 NSLog(@"%@", [receivedDict description]);
```

Comment: when I store my data without Archive my program is going crashed

Comment: 2014-10-31 15:17:04.250 iLogInAndRegister[2313:89344] my User default Data Is <userRegistrationClass: 0x7f8f70dd7e00>   its not worked perfect but we can say its worked

Comment: Create a method names as description in userRegistrationClass class. In this method, write down all the code to print properties and they will be printed.